# Java generics - Supertype references

Tags: java, generics, scjp, ocpjp

If i have understood generics correctly, a method with parameters declared as `<? super T>` will accept any reference that is either of Type `T` or a super type of `T`. I am trying to test this with the following bit of code but the compiler does not like it.

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}

class ZiggyTest2{

    public static void main(String[] args){                 

        List<Animal> anim2 = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        anim2.add(new Animal());
        anim2.add(new Dog());
        anim2.add(new Cat());   

        testMethod(anim2);
    }

    public static void testMethod(ArrayList<? super Dog> anim){
        System.out.println("In TestMethod");
        anim.add(new Dog());
        //anim.add(new Animal());
    }
}
```

Compiler error is :

```
ZiggyTest2.java:16: testMethod(java.util.ArrayList<? super Dog>) in ZiggyTest2 cannot be applied to (java.util.List<Animal>)
                testMethod(anim2);
                ^
1 error
```

I dont understand why i cant pass in anim2 since it is of type `<Animal>` and Animal is a super type of Dog.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass an expression of type `List<>` into a parameter of type `ArrayList<>`. Not going to work.

Either this line

```
public static void testMethod(ArrayList<? super Dog> anim){
```

should be

```
public static void testMethod(List<? super Dog> anim){
```

or

```
    List<Animal> anim2 = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

should be

```
    ArrayList<Animal> anim2 = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<? extends Dog>` ?

Also can I ask why you are using `ArrayList<? super Dog>` rather than just `ArrayList<Animal>`? Perhaps this example is just a simple form of what you are trying to do but it seems inexplicably over complicated.

This is a basic example of generics. Hope it helps.

```
class Animal{
public sleep(){}
}
class Dog extends Animal{
public sleep(){
    log("Dog sleeps");
}
}
class Rabbit extends Animal{
public sleep(){
    log("Rabbit sleeps");
}
}

class Place<T>{
T animal;
}
class Kennel extends Place<Dog>{
public Kennel(Dog dog){
    super();
    this.animal = dog;
}
}
class Hutch extends Place<Rabbit>{
public Kennel(Rabbit rabbit){
    super();
    this.animal = rabbit;
}
}
```

Comment: <? extends Dog> does not allow modifying the collection.

Comment: it also does not allow Dog list to be passed to test method.

Answer (score 0):

A nice document/introduction about Java Generics can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)